# How to implement UI theming with Angular without performance reduction?

Tags: angular, theming

**Background**

I have an Angular web application much like Facebook in its complexity. One of the main features is visual customization, which means a user can change every color on the website at run time and save color configuration to his profile.

I managed to achieve such a behavior by utilizing NgRx Store, where all the colors are stored and replicated on the entire application. Colors are assigned to each template element via Angular `[style.property]` notation.

**Problem**

I noticed that on the page with a list with many items (about 500) CPU usage gets high values and UI starts slowing down.

I think this is because there are many events emitted which I need to create css hover effect:

```
(mouseenter)="$event.target.style.backgroundColor = COLOR_2"
(mouseleave)="$event.target.style.backgroundColor = COLOR_1">
```

**Question**

Is there a way to eliminate performance reduction or use another theming approach which will not harm performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the color to each component you could create a theme directive that would create a style element on the head of the document which contains a `theme` class. You can then use this class to properly color all your elements.

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTheme]'
})
export class ThemeDirective {

  @Input()
  set appTheme(val: string) {
    this.setColor(val);
  }

  private themeElement: HTMLStyleElement;

  private setColor(color: string) {
    if(!this.themeElement) {
      this.themeElement = document.createElement('style');
      this.themeElement.type = 'text/css';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(this.themeElement);
      document.body.className = 'theme';
    }
    this.themeElement.innerHTML = `.theme { background-color: ${color}; }`;
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azxuvn